# Как работать с wordpress на двух пк?

Tags: wordpress, github, openserver, hosting

Нужен совет как лучше работать с wordpress с двух ПК.
Кратко, я верстальщик + знаю пхп. С цмс умею работать с modx. Решил выучить wordpress (все таки он очень популярный). Но в своей работе я пользуюсь двумя ПК. Например я могу работать днем на одном, а после вечером нужно продолжить дома на личном пк.
Увидел решения задачи в двух вариантах:

1. Использовать удалённый сервер (хостинг). Настроить в редакторе автоматическую синхронизацию (на сколько это возможно) в обеих пк. Но что то мне этот вариант не особо нравится, синхронизация работает не очень хорошо. Часто возникают проблемы.
2. Использовать опенсервер, нужный каталог для работы залить в репозиторий на ГитХаб. И в общем работаю на одном, закончил - залил. Дома нужно, то обновил с репозитория и работаю далее. Но так Ок все при верстке или простых пхп скриптах.

Как лучше именно при работе с цмс? Есть ли у кого такая практика и какой вариант предпочтительный, а то уже неделю все тыкаюсь с одного метода на другой и не знаю как правильно в обще в таком случаи люди работают. Заранее спасибо за советы )

---

Спасибо за ответы, подтолкнули до следующих размышлений. Изначально я выбрал вариант работы с удалёным сервером - создал поддомен и вроде Ок. Но проблемы адекватной синхронизации давали о себе знать. Например я удалил плагин и на текущем пк и сервере удалились все его файлы - Ок, но придя домой нужно помнить что на уже на этом ПК те все каталоги есть и нужно их удалять вручную. Полноценная синхронизация с локальным проектом и сервером не происходит, ковырял я что vscode что phpstorm.

Я вот подумываю что все таки Вы верно говорите что лучше использовать GIT, но чтоб комфортно было работать, тогда в репозитории нужно держать весь локальный сервер из сайтом (тогда да, база данных также будет одна, так как по сути mysql это такие же файлы). Почитал, смотрю гит дает 1 гб. на юзера. Каталог из сервером + сайт занимает до 10 гиг. Немного смущает что работа будет с такими большими объемами, с таким я еще не сталкивался... но нужно попробовать ))

Comment: Никто держит базы в git. Также ядро WP, сторонние плагины и всякие картинки. В git должен попадать только разрабатываемый код (тема, плагин). Код должен идти снизу вверх (локалка->сервер), а база + картинки сверху вниз (сервер->локалка). Картинки (uploads) можно вообще цеплять с сервера, достаточно настроить .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю Вам использовать третий вариант (сам пользуюсь) - купил хостинг на год, купил домен, при этом основной домен не трогаю, а создал несколько поддоменов, таким образом на каждом из них прикрутил свой сайт. Удобно тем, что могу хоть из кафе с чужого компьютера зайти в админку и работать с содержимым сайта.

Comment: Работать с содержимым сайта и заниматься его разработкой -- немного разные вещи)

Comment: В случае с Wordpress почти никакой разницы, ведь Вы создали копию шаблона, а также через админку имеете доступ ко всем файлам этого шаблона.

Comment: @Simon а как можно заниматься разработкой сайта не трогая БД? Или всякие гитхабы умеют синхронизировать БД с сайтом?

Comment: К слову сказать, в моем варианте, я могу получить доступ к БД с админки на хостинге через phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Дмитрий ну да, ну да, композер пакеты тоже через админку ставите/обновляете и консольные команды запускаете, создаете новые файлы через нее же?

Comment: @SeVlad никак, ну так и речь о полноценной работе/разработке, понятно что через админ панель это далеко не то, так как человек написал именно о работе с "содержимым", а не с чем-то еще.

Comment: Тогда идеальный сценарий для работы с полным содержимым, включая БД - работать через RDP, настройте доступ на рабочем компе и никогда его не выключайте, чтобы можно было зайти с домашнего.

Comment: @Simon полноценная разработка сайта невозможна без работы в админке. Это факт. А вот чтобы работать с файлами достаточно редактора/IDE и ftp (да и то не обязательно строго говоря. Хотя конечно так будет правильнее).

Comment: Этот третий вариант и есть мой перый вариант. Возможно не совсем доступно изначально описал суть проблемы.

Comment: @SeVlad я не утверждаю обратного, речь была о том что человек купил хостинг и через админку работает с сайтом и это удобно, так как можно зайти и работать хоть с чужого компа в кафе, я не думаю что на чужой комп в кафе кто-то будет накатывать IDE, FTP и прочее.

Answer (score 2):

Код должен быть в GitHub в любом случае. Вам нужна история изменений, автоматические тесты (в будущем), возможность работать нескольким девелоперам (ветки) и прочее.

При синхронизации на внешний сервер вам придётся использовать git локально и на сервере. Кроме того, в какой-то момент у вас появится автоматическая компиляция sсss и минификация файлов. Вам нужен будет gulp или webpack, которые придется запускать локально и на сервере.

Это краткий перечень проблем, которые встречаются при современной командной разработке. Поэтому, ведущие международные продуктовые компании ведут разработку плагинов и тем локально, с обменом результатов через GitHub/GitLab/BitBucket. При таком подходе количество используемых компьютеров для одного разработчика не ограничено.

Comment: Опять эти ваши однозначные "в любом случае".. Не в любом! Коммандная работа - это одно, а разработка в одно лицо - другое. С гитами всё замечательно когда касается только кода. Но разработка сайта - это далеко не только код. Поэтому гиты при одиночной работе  нафик не нужны. Лишниее звено (тем более с политикой становится рискованным и ненадёжным).

Comment: Я всегда использую git - в том числе и при разработке в одно лицо. Это позволяет "вспомнить все", понять изменения, откатить проблемные коммиты и т.д.

Comment: А я никогда не использую. Ибо лишнее это. И многие другие тоже не используют. (Это я к тому, что утверждения "в любом случае" не является сколь-нибудь достоверным. Как и "локальная разработка".. тема отдельных.. [ненужных] споров :))

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант является наиболее предпочтительным в целом. Работа с git упростит жизнь не только вам, но и другим людям, занятым в разработке сейчас или привлеченным в будущем.